# Breaking down totals by Agent then by day

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to change this query so it gives me a break down of total calls per agent by day.

Currently I have it working for a single day, but I'm trying to see if I can use the same query to grab every day of the week.

Here is what it is currently returning:

```
extension   Agent   MondayTotalCalls
237         Agent 1       62
275         Agent 2       63
233         Agent 3       58
272         Agent 4       65
245         Agent 5       61
236         Agent 6        2
239         Agent 7       45
```

Here is the query I am currently using:

```
select 
     u.extension
    ,u.firstname + ' ' + u.lastname as Agent
    ,count(s.notablecallid) as MondayTotalCalls
from ##session s
inner join ##callsummary cs on cs.notablecallid = s.notablecallid
inner join ##mxuser u on u.extensionid = s.extensionid2
inner join ##acdgroup g on s.serviceextension2 = g.extension
where g.extension in ('700', '702')
and s.creationtimestamp between @monday_start_datetime and @monday_end_datetime
group by u.firstname, u.lastname, u.extension
```

I have other variables already built in the query that may be helpful.

I have two variables for each day `starttime` and `endtime` (monday-friday)
I have a `daterange` for the specific week needed `@converted_start_datetime` and `@converted_end_datetime`

The entire `daterange` of data is put into each table `##session`, `##callsummary` etc.

For each agent I need the totals for each day of the week.

Comment: Can you provide us with the sample data. You have given the output but not the sample data

Answer (score 0):

I think aggregating by `datename(weekday, creationtimestamp)` would do what you want:

```
select datename(weekday, creationtimestamp) as dow, u.extension
       u.firstname + ' ' + u.lastname as Agent,
       count(s.notablecallid) as MondayTotalCalls
from ##session s inner join
     ##callsummary cs
     on cs.notablecallid = s.notablecallid inner join
     ##mxuser u
     on u.extensionid = s.extensionid2 inner join
     ##acdgroup g
     on s.serviceextension2 = g.extension
where g.extension in ('700', '702') @monday_end_datetime
group by datename(weekday, creationtimestamp), u.firstname, u.lastname, u.extension
order by min(creationtimestamp);
```

Comment: I tried this method and it got me thinking a bit differently.  I can't use this exact method without a bit more formatting.  The UTC dates carry over into the next day.  But I'm going to play around with this a bit I do like what it does.